# How to bind Row Header in wpf datagrid?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, row

In my project i want datagrid row header values like outlook calendar. For assuming that is 9.00, 9.30, 10.00, 10.30.... But its not fixed one, it may vary,.. 9.00 pm, 10.00 pm.

i am using two TextBlock for this and i got almost same shape too. but my values are fixed one that is 1-00, 1-00,1-00, 1-00,1-00, 1-00,........

My Code-

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="560" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,54,0,0" Name="myDataGrid" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="884" MouseDoubleClick="myDataGrid_MouseDoubleClick" IsEnabled="True" SelectionUnit="Cell">
        <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="1" Foreground="#9493CF" FontSize="16" />
                        <TextBlock Text="00" Foreground="#9493CF" />
                    </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                <ContextMenu x:Name="LeftClickMenu">
                    <MenuItem Header="New Appointment" Click="MenuItem_Click"/>
                    <!--<MenuItem Header="Save"/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Print"/>-->
                    <Separator/>
                    <MenuItem Header="Exit"/>
                </ContextMenu>
            </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid>
```

What I want -

[image]

What I Got -

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Binding not working in WPF Datagrid second row header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20854225/binding-not-working-in-wpf-datagrid-second-row-header)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>You can specify `negative top margin` on second textBlock:</s>

```
<TextBlock Text="00" Foreground="#9493CF" Margin="1,-5,0,0"/>
```

**Output with negative top margin:**

[image]

**Output without margin:**

[image]

**Update**:

In case you want header to be customizable, you need to have `one property in your model class`(*object representing row*) say `Time` which will be different for different rows. For first row Time value will be 9, second 10 and so on.

Then you can bind to that property like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" 
            HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Time,
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                                                AncestorType=DataGridRowHeader}}"
                Foreground="#9493CF" FontSize="16" />
    <TextBlock Text="00" Foreground="#9493CF" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: sir i want to set the value,  9.00, 9.30, 10.00, 10.30.... like this, but i got 1 00, 1 00,1 00, 1 00,1 00, 1 00,1 00, 1 00.. that is my question. How can i set the values in row header

Comment: I got 00,00,00 only. explain property also sir

Comment: What's `ItemSource` property for your DataGrid?

Comment: my project https://skydrive.live.com/#cid=49987984BACC2BE0&id=49987984BACC2BE0%21106

download my project, and see the source code sir.

Comment: no sir i can't get the values,. bzs i don't know how to bind the row hedaer.

Comment: Item doesn't exist on path you mentioned.

Comment: Ok great. You should read more about `Binding` and `MVVM`. That will help you understand the concept for sure.