# Binding not working in WPF Datagrid second row header

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

My Xaml-

```
 <Grid>
        <DataGrid Name="DataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock Text="19" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Items.Year, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=DataGridRowHeader}}" Foreground="#9493CF" FontSize="16" />                        
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowHeaderTemplate>
            <DataGrid.Columns>                
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Course" Binding="{Binding Path=Course}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>        
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

in C#

```
  var itemList = new List<Items>();

  itemList.Add(new Items { Year = 22, Course = "B.SC", Name = "Jegadees" });
  itemList.Add(new Items { Year = 23, Course = "M.SC", Name = "Arun" });
  itemList.Add(new Items { Year = 55, Course = "B.Tech", Name = "Kanaga" });

  DataGrid.ItemsSource = itemList;
```

Item Collection -

```
 public class Items
    {        
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Course { get; set; }
        public int Year { get; set; }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bind Row Header in wpf datagrid?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781564/how-to-bind-row-header-in-wpf-datagrid)

Answer (score 3):

The ancestor with a DataContext of Item is the DataGridRow of the corosponding DataGridRowHeader

```
 <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Year, 
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                            AncestorType=DataGridRow}}" />
```

Comment: i changed the path to Path=Year becuase the DataContext is an "Items" (object) not a property of it . see edit

Comment: thanks sir,. <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                      AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, 
                                      Path=Item.Year}"  /> is working fine

Comment: do you know how to use snoop ?

Comment: @Sagotharan i don't understand how this worked before , see edit .

Comment: i am also not aware of this sir, if you want to check or see my project, you can download in sky drive.. https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=49987984bacc2be0&id=49987984BACC2BE0!175#cid=49987984BACC2BE0&id=49987984BACC2BE0!106

Comment: @Sagotharan - Earlier it was working because you used this path `Path=Item.Year`. Item is property on DataGridRow which corresponds to DataContext only. Also my answer would have work. Have you tried that? Not sure why it's downvoted anyhow.

Comment: s sir, why my question has downvoted?, i do't know. but its not a matter.

Comment: I would like to go back in time and tell the younger me to ignore this question.

Comment: I would do the same instead and want to ignore this. +1 for you eran..!!

Comment: i up voted you as well before .

by the way all these accusations about who down voted who , you guys do realize that any one of the 55 people who viewed this question could of down voted your posts .

Comment: Yeah true. Down voter must have down voted out of boredom after reading so many comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

With this piece of code `RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRowHeader}}"`, you are travelling upto Visual Tree till you find  first `DataGridRowHeader`.

Issue is in your Path - `Path=Items.Year`.

**It will search for property `Items` in DataGridRowHeader which obviously it doesn't have.**

You need to change Path to like this `DataContext.Year` because `DataContext` will get you actual object it's binded to i.e. an *instance of Items class and then bind to its property `Year` in that instance.*

So correct binding would be like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=DataContext.Year,
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, 
                                    AncestorType=DataGridRowHeader}/>
```

Comment: I Think i missed that i didn't give DataContext. in my answer and now that i think about it , it is needed since it will search for Year in DataGridRow properties , how could this have worked for him .
in addition he needs AncestorType=DataGridRow since the DataGridRowHeader does not have the same datacontext by default for some reason .

Comment: No `DataGridRowHeader` will have the same DataContext set to the one which is set to `DataGridRow`. I guess you are misinterpreting it with `DataGridColumnHeader` which does not have DataContext. I have tested this code and it's working with no issues.

Comment: no i would expect it to have the same DataContext i'm not misinterpreting , i just came across a situation where for some reason it did not have the same DataContext as the DataGridRow , i'll check it out and post it here later , 

FYI , if it has the same datacontext you could have just written 

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Year}" />

Comment: @eranotzap - FYI is wrong. It's coming back again in circle. Like mentioned above, first i need to travel upto `DataGridRowHeader` and need to access DataContext otherwise it will search for year in DataGridRowHeader. How this will work - `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Year}" />`?

Comment: You are mistaken , if you do not state RelativeSource it will search for Year in the current DataContext of the TextBlock element which it inherits from it's parent the DataGridRowHeader .

Comment: @eran - I have updated the answer for your comments. Please have a look. Hope it answers all your queries. :)

Comment: You miss understood me completely  , you've just said the same point i was trying to make . 

1) DataGridRowHeader does not inherit DataGridRow's DataContext 
2) If it had , like you claimed in your answer i said that you could of just written "{Binding Year}" which wouldn't work for reason number (1)

Comment: Leave it. We are running in circles ;) Happy new year mate.. :)

Comment: I didn't , i should have but i let it be, it wasn't me .

Comment: You should have? Seriously? My answer was working and your's not and you improve that after my answer but i didn't downvoted it.

Comment: Earlier code was this - `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Year,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=DataGridRow}}"/>` whisch wasn't working.

Comment: OP accepted answer because which worked was this - `<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=Item.Year}" />`.

Comment: I have already left comment over there that why it was working.

Comment: yes , that's true , i didn't understand why he accepted it , i corrected it , the discussion is about RelativeSource is it DataGridRow or DataGridRowHeader m does DataGridRowHeader inherit it's DataContext from DataGridRow or not ..

Comment: It might not be always but in this case `DataGridRowHeader` is inheriting DataContext that's why my posted answer is also working. I hope with this we can rest this case. No hard feelings..!!